# Implementing Undo/Redo functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-select, undo-redo

I'm trying to implement a drop down undo/redo menu similar to the ones that can be found in Windows. I already have a backing `ObservableCollection<T>` that stores the stack of actions correctly and currently have a `ListView` displaying them.

I'm not currently sure how to go about implementing the feature that highlights all the items above the current selection. My current thoughts are that one of the following would be best:

- Add attracted properties to the `List ViewItem`s
- Derive from `ListViewItem` and implement the functionality with dependency properties, provided I can get `ListView` to use this class as the item container.
- Completely start fresh with a derivation of `ItemsControl`

I'm new to programming in WPF and C#, so I'd appreciate any advice that can be offered.

Comment: You could utilize the `AlternationCount` and [`AlternationIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to highlight all items with an AlternationIndex that is less than (or equal to) the SelectedIndex property of the ListView.

Comment: As a note, to make an ItemsControl use your custom item container class, override its `GetContainerForItemOverride` method.